# Is it possible to use a laptop as an external monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display

I need to create a multi-monitor setup for my desktop computer but I have no additional monitors with me right now, aside from my laptop. Is it possible to use my laptop screen as an external monitor?

Note that I am **not** trying to connect a monitor to my laptop, rather, I am trying to connect my laptop screen to a desktop video card (if this is possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something sort-of similar using [synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/); you can control both computers from one mouse and keyboard using your network connection.  This isn't quite the same thing, since windows won't drag from one machine to another.  On the other hand, it does give you more processing power at your disposal, so it's a bit of a tradeoff.

Comment: as a note synergy is cross-platform. but sadly undeveloped the last I checked.

Comment: that's why you use Synergy+ (http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/)

Comment: QSynergy is even better!  adds a GUI to Synergy+:  http://lifehacker.com/5515093/qsynergy-makes-multi+system-control-easier-and-prettier?skyline=true&s=i

Comment: Synergy+ would be great if it worked with vmware on the client... but it seems that I can't use shift, ctrl, or alt.  Bug report: http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=10

Answer (score 3):

Check out this webpage from Alternativeto.com...it lists the (mostly) free alternatives to Maxivista...as good of a list as you're gonna get...

http://alternativeto.net/desktop/maxivista/

Answer (score 2):

I´ve got the same problem at work. After a bit of searching the web I found [this](http://www.maxivista.com/) piece of software. It´s called MaxiVista and provides the use of other Computers as monitor. You can move your mouse over the screens like you plugged them directly onto your Computer.

Comment: however, Maxivista costs $40!

Comment: yeah but the trial version lets you use up to three computers as monitors. but I´m glad you posted that list :-)

Comment: ya, MaxiVista is a killer app, just wish it were free/less expensive! Kind of boggles my mind to think about what MaxiVista does, to tell you the truth! :)